# Communication between kernel and shell

Tags: linux, shell, operating-system

I had a query regarding kernels and shells in general.
Is it possible for an OS to run multiple shells at the same time or is there just one shell and one kernel?

Lets take Ubuntu for example.
Does the Unity desktop environment and the terminal communicate with the same shell or are there different shells interacting with the kernel?

Could someone please explain the structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all, read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con)**.

From that definition you see that a shell is the **interpreter** itsself and is **just a process**. Since all Unix-derivatives support multitasking, multiple processes **and therefore shells** can be executed concurrently.

When you are in a bash session you can just start a new shell by executing the `bash` executable, for example. Then you have two "nested" shells.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible for an OS to run multiple shells at the same time or is
> there just one shell and one kernel??
>
> Ans1. Yes Multiple shell can run one single kernel provider the kernel
> supports multi threading today all most the kernel supports.
>
> Does the unity desktop environment and the terminal communicate with
> the same shell or are there different shells interacting with the
> kernel?
>
> Ans2. No bot are running in different shell but on a same kernel That
> is why u can get the list of files reside in desktop by `ls-ltr`
>
> Could someone please explain the structure ?
>
> 1st is core that is your computer H/W that is interacted by kernel on
> top of it all shells are running That includes your GUI,Terminal,Shell
> scripts.

you can refer this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-getting-started.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the shell depends upon the OS. In Unix, shells are merely programs (and almost any program can be a shell). In other systems the relationship between the process and the shell is more complex. In VMS, for example, the shell can exist concurrently with a program in the process, with the shell residing in a protected mode.

In any event, most system allow multiple shells to run at the same time.